# SVG line in y=mx+c format

Tags: svg, line

I want to draw an **SVG line** given the **slope and the constant term** or the `y = mx + c`  format.

Is there a direct way to do this in SVG or an indirect way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you already have axes drawn and want to overlay this, or are you wanting something to draw an entire graph? A line of y=mx+c (especially the c part) does not mean much on its own.

Comment: my coordinate system is the default svg one as I am not dealing with graphs but with pure Euclidean geometry. So this is an helper function for drawing lines passing through given point and inclined to another line by an angle of theta. Also I want the line to be of infinite length (at least fit canvas).

Comment: Also it is used to find intersection of two circles by first finding out the radical axis.

Comment: In SVG, you can only draw line *segments* not *straight* lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<line>` tag only supports start and end attributes (`x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`). As such, you'll need to pick x coordinates outside your canvas manually and use `y2` = `y1` + m(`x2` - `x1`).

**Edit**

Looking through the spec, it's possible to transform individual elements as required:

```
<line ... transform="translate(x, y) rotate(theta)" />
```

Where `theta` is the angle of clockwise rotation in degrees.

So you could draw a long horizontal line from (-10000, 0) to (10000, 0), say, and then apply the appropriate rotation and translation to position it:

```
<line x1="-10000" y1="0" x2="10000" y2="0" transform="translate(150, 200) rotate(-30)" />
```

Will draw a (seemingly endless) line through (150, 200) of slope π/6 radians.

Comment: Yes, that is what i am doing. but does svg support floating point coordinates?

Comment: @MeghParikh Yes it does.

Comment: @MeghParikh As per the documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGLength).

Comment: Thanks. But still I am keeping the question open for another solution.

Comment: @MeghParikh Check my example jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8PQET/5). You can adjust the line by changing the textboxes.

Comment: Thanks,it works perfectly . I would upload my library on github as egeo or jsgeo on meghprkh.github.com

Comment: Sorry , github.com/meghprkh/

Comment: @MeghParikh Go ahead. I wouldn't be able assert copyright on something like that even if I had any intention of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is a good means of showing geometry. However, you must know some Javascript to build the dynamic display.

Below is an example that you can copy into your HTML file and view it in the browser.
It shows drawing a line from two points, then extending it to the end of the viewable svg viewing area (400x400), using the equation `y=mx+c`. Note, that the y-axis in svg begins at the upper-left, where y coordinates extends **downward** as the positive direction.

Drawing the line and extending it uses a bit of javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Draw Line y=mx+b</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
<h4>Draw Line y=mx+b</h4>
Red line is original points. Dashed extends to start(0)/end(400) of x axis
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<line id="myLine2" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="10 10" />
<line id="myLine1" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
</div>
  <br />SVG Source:<br />
<textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:200px'></textarea>
  <br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>
<div id='browserDiv' style='padding:5px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;background-color:gainsboro;'>OK in:IE11/CH32/FF23<br /></div>
<script id=myScript>
function DrawLineToAxis()
{
    var x1=120
    var y1=150
    var x2=360
    var y2=290
    var m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    myLine1.setAttribute("x1",x1)
    myLine1.setAttribute("y1",y1)
    myLine1.setAttribute("x2",x2)
    myLine1.setAttribute("y2",y2)

    /*
    y=m*x-m*120+150
    */
    //---extend to x=0 x=400
    x1=0
    y1=-m*120+150
    x2=400
    y2=m*x2-m*120+150

    myLine2.setAttribute("x1",x1)
    myLine2.setAttribute("y1",y1)
    myLine2.setAttribute("x2",x2)
    myLine2.setAttribute("y2",y2)
}

</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    DrawLineToAxis()
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
    jsValue.value=myScript.text
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Following is my code :

```js
function linemc(m,c){
var x,y,xm=[],ym=[];

x=-1;y=m*x+c;if(y>=0&&y<ysize) {xm.push(x);ym.push(y);}
x=xsize+1;y=m*x+c;if(y>=0&&y<ysize) {xm.push(x);ym.push(y);}

y=-1;x=(y-c)/m;if(x>=0&&x<xsize+1) {xm.push(x);ym.push(y);}
y=ysize+1;x=(y-c)/m;if(x>=0&&x<xsize+1) {xm.push(x);ym.push(y);}

return new line(xm[0],ym[0],xm[1],ym[1]);
}
```

where new line just creates a DOM node for line by accepting four arguments

and xsize and ysize is size of canvas